# prop.test or chi squared test on count data with 3 groups?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, proportion, count-data

I have some count data pertaining to number of events observed among independent trials in 3 groups of an experiment:

```
count   A    B    C
0       5    0    5
1       1   25    9
2       9   30   10
3       3   15    8
4       4   13    9
5       4   13    5
6       1    6    8
7       2    4    6
8       0   10    1
9       4    5    2
10      0    5    3
```

A Kruskal-Wallis test leads me to conclude that the distribution of numbers of events observed does not differ significantly between groups. However, I'd also like to know whether getting a specific event count is statistically more likely in the different groups. In particular I'm interested in event counts of zero or 1. For example, an event count of 1 is proportionately much more likely in group B compared with groups A or C. I'd like to test for the significance of this.

I have looked at using a chi-squared test to compare proportions between groups for a specific outcome but believe this may be invalid due to low frequencies of observation (<5) for some numbers of events. In this case, would R's `prop.test` be more suitable?

EDIT: post updated to make data easy to copy-and-paste

Comment: It's **_expected frequencies_**, not observed frequencies, that constrain a chi-square test. Avoiding expected frequencies $< 5$ was shown to be paranoid decades ago: many more recent authorities cite avoiding tables with any $< 1$ as a rule of thumb while not denying the need for caution.

Comment: Could you show your data in a form suitable for copy-and-paste? Presenting tables as images cuts down mightily on the number of people who might play with your data to give other perspectives.

Comment: (Previous comment deleted).  For what you are asking, I think one approach is to construct a 2 x 3 table of counts with e.g. "1" and "Not-1" for A, B, and C. You could run a chi-square test or Fisher's exact on that table.... But looking at your data, it seems strange that you want to look at only, say, counts for "1" events. Is there something special about "1" vs. "2" or "0" relative to the rest?

Comment: I think your instinct to use Kruskal-Wallis was a good one.  But comparing the distributions with a chi-square test of association on the whole table may also make sense.  The expected counts for the whole table are pretty small.  (Maybe 15% are less than 2).  So you might want to use an exact test (fisher.test) or Monte Carlo: `library(coin); chisq_test(Table, distribution=approximate(B=100000))`. For a visual: `library(lattice); histogram(~Counts.f | Group, data = All, layout = c(1,3), col="gray")`

Comment: @SalMangiafico your first suggestion is something I had considered. There is something interesting from our perspective about the "0" and "1" cases. The Kruskal-Wallis test result has provided some insight but as I say we are also keen to look specifically at these outcomes. Thanks for the tip on running an exact test - I'll look into this and come back with comments.

Comment: @SalMangiafico, I've run the chisq_test as you suggested. I'm getting a test statistic of 95.63, p-value < 2.2e-16. So this would imply that event count and group number are not independent, correct? I'm confused as to how to interpret this with regards to the Kruskal-Wallis result (no difference between event-count distributions) - can you help?

Comment: @allhands, your confusion stems from the fact that you have the hypothesis for the K-W test incorrect.  Unfortunately people have the tendency --- either being sloppy or trying to simplify things --- to say that Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney and K-W test the distribution of the data in the groups.  This is misleading.  They test the probability that an observation from one group will be higher in rank than from another group.  The null is stochastic equality among the groups.  Practically, they test if one group has higher values than another, not if the distributions differ in some other way.

Comment: @SalMangiafico so as in NickCox's comment below it looks like the K-W test is not sensitive to the different fine structure in the data. Is there a tool to do some post-hoc analysis to see where/how the groups differ?

Comment: For post-hoc, sometimes people look at standardized residuals or odds ratio. For me, the most logical way to is break down the table pairwise.  In this case, you would construct a table with A and B, one with A and C, and one with B and C. Be sure to apply a p-value correction for multiple tests.  [There are some functions used here that automate this process](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_04.html).  As mentioned above, if you are looking specifically at, say, a count of "1", you can construct a 2x3 table of counts for "1" and "not-1". Again, be aware that you are making multiple hyp tests.

Comment: The difference between K-W and chi-square isn't about sensitivity to "fine structure";  they test completely different hypotheses.  The K-W is about if observations in one group are higher than the others.  Contrast this with the 2-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test, which tests for a difference in distribution.  Imagine you have two groups, one has a bell-shaped distribution and one has a uniform distribution, and they have about the same center and spread.  Mann-Whitney tests says no reason to think values for one are greater than the other, but in fact the _distributions_ are very different.

Comment: Understood. So there is no reason that the K-W and chi-square results could not be used in conjunction with one another? Running the post-hoc `pairwiseNominalIndependence` test with `fdr` p-value correction between (for example) groups A and B indicates significant differences (`p.adj.Chisq<0.05`) for comparisons `0:1, 0:2, 0:3, 0:8`. The interpretation being that it's on these event counts that the groups differ. I just want to be certain I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are intending to do.  For the pairwise comparisons, I was thinking comparing among A, B, and C for all Count levels.  In this case, I get A and C are not different, and both are different from B.  You could do the same with the Counts variable, but this is different from what we talking about earlier, which would be to compare "1" to all "not 1", not to compare "1" to each other Count individually.  It really depends on what you are trying to determine.

Comment: Yes I see that setting `compare="column"` I get the result you describe. To answer the second part of your comment it would be informative to get a handle on where the groups differ. But having thought more now about the question we're asking I'm less sure if this is now relevant. If there's a way to condense this discussion into a single answer then I will accept it as solving the problem - many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your chi-square result. This is what I get in Stata:

```
          observed frequency
          expected frequency

----------------------------------
          |         which         
    count |      A       B       C
----------+-----------------------
        0 |      5       0       5
          |  1.467   5.600   2.933
          | 
        1 |      1      25       9
          |  5.133  19.600  10.267
          | 
        2 |      9      30      10
          |  7.187  27.440  14.373
          | 
        3 |      3      15       8
          |  3.813  14.560   7.627
          | 
        4 |      4      13       9
          |  3.813  14.560   7.627
          | 
        5 |      4      13       5
          |  3.227  12.320   6.453
          | 
        6 |      1       6       8
          |  2.200   8.400   4.400
          | 
        7 |      2       4       6
          |  1.760   6.720   3.520
          | 
        8 |      0      10       1
          |  1.613   6.160   3.227
          | 
        9 |      4       5       2
          |  1.613   6.160   3.227
          | 
       10 |      0       5       3
          |  1.173   4.480   2.347
----------------------------------

16 cells with expected frequency < 5

          Pearson chi2(20) =  42.0876   Pr = 0.003
 likelihood-ratio chi2(20) =  47.3624   Pr = 0.001
```

We can note:

1. Strong rejection of lack of association. Plainly put, the groups really are different.
2. Caveat: several small expected frequencies.
3. Caveat: The chi-square test pays no attention to the ordering 0 ... 10 or what those values are. They are just 11 categories.

The distributions do look different.

[image]

I can't comment helpfully on the idea of focusing on 0 and 1. I am not a routine user of R and haven't looked at `prop.test`, but note that it is best to phrase questions in terms of statistical issues, not the software you happen to be using.

Comment: Thanks for this. Your chi-square output is the same, in that we reject independence of the variables (event count and group), i.e. there is some association between them. But the Kruskal-Wallis result indicates that we cannot reject the null hypothesis that the samples are from the same distribution. So on one hand chi-square says there is an effect between group and event count, but on the other KW says they are not different. Am I mis-interpreting something here?

Comment: The "prop.test" function tests whether proportions between groups are the same. To run this I believe the data would need to be mapped as "success" and "failure", or "event count = 1" vs. "event count != 1" in my example.

Comment: We don't get the same chi-square test statistic, so we did something different. You can see my set-up but I can't see yours.

Comment: Evidently Kruskal-Wallis is not sensitive to the different fine structure.

Comment: Using @SalMangiafico's suggested code, in R, `library(coin); chisq_test(count_freqs, distribution=approximate(B=100000))` where `count_freqs` is the data table gives `chi-squared = 95.626, p-value < 2.2e-16`

Comment: I suggest that you explain what that means. Otherwise (a) you're dependent on people having run that to know what is different (b) I can't comment further. A chi-square test here should be the same across all competent programs. As before I can only infer that you're doing something differently but I don't know what.

Comment: That is to say: I understand that a P-value could be very different if it were established by simulation. I don't understand how the chi-square statistic is so different.

Comment: For the Monte Carlo (coin :: chisq_test), I got (approximately) `chi-squared = 42.088, p-value = 0.00259`, just about the same as the usual chi-squared test.

Comment: @SalMangiafico That's fine and I'm just showing fewer d.p. on the P-value.  OP's different results remain.

Comment: @NickCox apologies I believe I made an error in constructing the data table. I'm now getting the same result as SalMangiafico

Comment: In short, small expected frequencies aren't biting: I suggested earlier that they have to really small for that to happen. The P-value is trustworthy and its implications clear. If you want to follow up the issue of small counts @SalMangiafico has made specific suggestions. under the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are mainly interested in knowing how to interpret the test results when there are more than two categories. Particularly, as you stated: "I would like to know whether getting a specific event count is statistically more likely in the different groups"

Therefore, I am sharing a brief script that I use in such situations:

```
# Load the required packages:
library(MASS) # for chisq
library(descr) # for crosstable

CrossTable(a$exam_result, a$ethnicity
       fisher = T, chisq = T, expected = T,
       prop.c = F, prop.t = F, prop.chisq = F, 
       sresid = T, format = 'SPSS')
```

This code will generate both Pearson's Chi-square and Fisher's Chi square. It produces counts as well as proportions of each of the table entries.
Based on the standardised residuals or z-values scores i.e.,

```
sresid
```

For each table entry, look at its sresid, whenever it is outside the range |1.96| i.e., less than -1.96 or greater than 1.96, then it is significant p < 0.05. 
And its sign would then indicate whether it is positively related or negatively.